# Same hop appears 4 times on a traceroute

Tags: ping, traceroute

When I traceroute bbc.co.uk in my home Network the first hop appears 4 times.
What could be causing this ?

```
@Latitude-7480 ~ $ tracepath bbc.co.uk
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1300
 1:  10.87.0.1                                             1.489ms 
 1:  10.87.0.1                                            23.899ms 
 1:  10.87.0.1                                             1.631ms 
 1:  10.87.0.1                                            28.040ms 
 2:  10.255.144.0                                         34.858ms 
 3:  172.16.212.252                                       75.383ms 
 4:  145.15.245.9                                        112.480ms 
 5:  145.15.245.26                                        38.264ms asymm  4 
 6:  ns.nikhef.jointtransit.nl                            46.137ms asymm  5 
 7:  be4784.ccr21.ams04.atlas.cogentco.com                34.456ms asymm  6 
 8:  be3457.ccr41.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com                33.586ms asymm  7
```

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about networks that are not under your direct control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to path MTU discovery.

As you can see the MTU for you first hop is 1300, while you computer expect 1500 by default.

So tracepath will send several packets to determine the correct MTU, and in this case it took 4 try to get it right.

Then it continue the trace to the destination.